# upload xlsx data at PHP without changing the header row color

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, xlsx

I have a problem in PhpExcel 2007.

the problem is : When I upload Excel to my directory and load it again,
the header of Excel changes from blue into white (blank).

Before upload: [image: before upload]

After upload, when I load the modified sheet again: [image: after upload and i load again to modified sheet]

Excel successfully saved into my folder, but header sheet 1 turned into blank color (it must remain blue, like I uploaded).

why blue row turn into white row :(

```
$location="../test/tes.xlsx";
$objPHPExcel=PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($location);

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex();

$objPHPExcel->createSheet();

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(2);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Error !!!');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Error Log');

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');

header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="tes.xlsx"');

header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');

$objWriter->save('php://output');

$objWriter->save("../testfolder/tes.xlsx");
```

Answer (score 0):

//try putting this after 2nd line in ur code
// here A1 is ur start column and you need to change F1 with respect to your end column

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:F1')->applyFromArray
        (
            array(
                    'fill' => array(
                        'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                        'color' => array('rgb' => 'DCDCDC')
                    )
                )
        );
```

Comment: i dont want to blue row turn into white row, just keep blue when i save excel into my folder